# Docker buildkit, new --mount command during build and large files in the context

Tags: docker, build, mount

If I have a very large file that I only need during build time, and If I use the following commands:

```
docker buildx build Dockerfile .
```

and then a line somewhere in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/target_path,readonly,source=large_dir_or_file
```

would that very large file still got send to the docker daemon? I am wondering if the --mount command offers any advantage here for the large files?

Also, if the docker context and daemon are on the same machine, are all the context files still sent/copied to a location where docker daemon can see them?

Thank you,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of

```
RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/target_path,readonly,source=large_dir_or_file something
```

over

```
COPY large_dir_or_file /target_path
RUN something
```

is that the big file will not bloat the layers of your docker image.

But yes, it must be in the context and it will be sent to the docker daemon even if it is local.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're working locally, the `docker build` command always sends a copy of the context directory over its socket to the Docker daemon.  If you have a very large build context (especially over a gigabyte in size) this is the step that prints out a percentage progress at the very beginning of the build sequence.

The build context is everything in and underneath the directory you pass to `docker build`, less anything that's in the [`.dockerignore` file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).  This will always get sent to the Docker daemon, local or remote, whether or not any given file is actually `COPY`ed into the image.

I'm guessing the BuildKit bind-mount option you show probably will work mechanically.  You need to make sure the large file is also in the `.dockerignore` file so it's not copied as part of the build context.  This will effectively prevent you from using a remote Docker daemon to build, if you or your CI system will ever do this, and it's not a typical pattern, but it should have a visible difference in build performance and more specifically in that initial "copying the build context" step.

You note in the question that this file is only used during your initial build sequence, and I'm guessing you copy the result of the build out using a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) so you have a much smaller image.  My past experience has been that operations like `docker push` and `docker pull` are unreliable with very large images, so if you can't remove this file from the final image you might need to inject it into the container in some other way.

Comment: David, many thanks for your answer. Maybe I will add a bit more context. The large file in my case contains some data that I use to train various models. In the end, I only retain the models, so the training data can be discarded. I use buildkit to mount the large data directory at build time. I have noticed that the mount command during build only works for a single RUN command. So I mount and then train the models as a single RUN. Then there is the next stage where I only copy models. I think if one uses mount, there is no need to copy data into the image which is always an advantage.

Comment: And your comment on adding the large file to .gitignore. Would that prevent the large file from being sent to docker daemon as a whole? I wish there was a bit more in the docs on that! Thank you

Comment: Adding the large file to `.dockerignore` (different file) prevents it from being sent to the Docker daemon.